# What is the fastest way to transfer view data between two Azure SQL Databases?

Tags: sql-server, azure, sqlbulkcopy

I need to transfer the data contained in a number of views in one read-only Azure SQL database to corresponding tables in another Azure SQL Database on the same logical server. These tables will be used for Data Sync with the destination server acting as a hub so it'l be a process repeated several times daily. Each view is around 200k rows which will grow. Both databases have enough DTUs assigned that they do not max out during the process.

It is technically simple to do with External tables or Bulk copy but performance is too slow.

-External tables/Elastic Query takes about 12-15 minutes to copy one view across

-Bulk copy via either Powershell on a cloud shell or Azure function is faster but times out when running in an Azure logic app as it takes more than 120 seconds to run for a single view copy. This means that the subsequent steps don't fire.

Transactional replication from a SQL managed instance is an option but it involves a significant cost increase.

It is an open question but is a bulk copy function as fast as it's going to get or am I missing another option?

The function code itself is a standard c# bulk copy

```
string Source = <Source Connection>; 
string Destination =  <DestinationConnection>;
 using (SqlConnection sourceCon = new SqlConnection(Source))  
  {  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM [dbo].[SOURCE_VIEW]", sourceCon);  
        sourceCon.Open();  
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())  
        {  
              using (SqlConnection destinationCon = new SqlConnection(Destination))  
              {  
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationCon))  
                    {  
                          bc.BatchSize = 10000;   
                          bc.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[DESTINATION_TABLE]";    
                          destinationCon.Open();  
                          bc.WriteToServer(rdr);   
                    }  
              }  
        }  
  }
```

Comment: Not related to performance improvement, but you could convert your function to a [Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) which the Logic App will allow to run for a very long time by using the Polling Consumer pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think about using [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction)?

It has the fast performance to transfer big data. Reference: [Copy performance and scalability achievable using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf):

[image]

You can learn from this tutorial: [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database).

This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from and to Azure SQL Database, and use Data Flow to transform data in Azure SQL Database.

Data Factory has many components can help you copy the data from many views to another Azure SQL database in one pipeline.

Hope this helps.